# only one item in listbox being updated?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

Hi I have the following code to search and the searched items are displayed in the listbox. I also have an update button that updates whatever new information you input in a textbox. the update box works fine but for some reason when multiple duplicated items are displayed in the listbox and i try to click the 2nd instance and try to update, it updates the original and not the 2nd instance. So, the first instance should update first instance item, and 2nd should update 2nd but right now, 1st is updating 1st instance, 2nd is updating 1st instance, 3rd is updating 1st instance - always updating the 1st instance. how can i fix this? this is the document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/36e9fmbf17wpa0l/example.xlsm

```
Public Sub Search_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim s As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim str() As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

Name = surname.Value

With ws
 Set f = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
  If Not f Is Nothing Then
   With Me
    firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
    tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
    program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
    email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text

    SetCheckBoxes f.Offset(0, 5) '<<< replaces code below

    officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
    cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 7).Text
    r = f.Row
   End With
    findnext
        FirstAddress = f.Address
Do
    s = s + 1
    Set f = Range("A:A").findnext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> FirstAddress
    If s > 1 Then
       Select Case MsgBox("There are " & s & " instances of " & Name, vbOKCancel Or vbExclamation Or vbDefaultButton1, "Multiple entries")

       Case vbOK
            findnext
       Case vbCancel

       End Select

    End If

Else: MsgBox Name & "Not Listed"

End If

End With

End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub findnext()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim findnext As Range

Name = surname.Value
Me.ListBox1.Clear
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
With ws
 Set f = .Cells(r, 1)
 Set findnext = f

With ListBox1
  Do
Debug.Print findnext.Address
Set findnext = Range("A:A").findnext(findnext)

.AddItem findnext.Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = findnext.Offset(0, 1).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = findnext.Offset(0, 2).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = findnext.Offset(0, 3).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = findnext.Offset(0, 4).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = findnext.Offset(0, 5).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = findnext.Offset(0, 6).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = findnext.Offset(0, 7).Value
.List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = findnext.Offset(0, 8).Value
Loop While findnext.Address <> f.Address
 End With
End With

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub update_Click()
MsgBox "Directorate has been updated!"
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
With ws
 Set f = .Cells(r, 1)

    f.Value = surname.Value
    f.Offset(0, 1).Value = firstname.Value
    f.Offset(0, 2).Value = tod.Value
    f.Offset(0, 3).Value = program.Value
    f.Offset(0, 4).Value = email.Value
    f.Offset(0, 5).Value = GetCheckBoxes
    f.Offset(0, 6).Value = officenumber.Value
    f.Offset(0, 7).Value = cellnumber.Value

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The first obvious problem is `r`.  This global is used as a temporary variable by `Search_Click` and as a master variable by `update_Click`.

Consider `update_Click`.  Near the beginning we have:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
With ws
  Set f = .Cells(r, 1)
```

If you load the form, fill the fields and click <kbd>Update</kbd> then `r` will not have been initialised so with have the default value of zero.

It is very difficult to guess what this form is attempting to achieve. Most of the buttons do nothing. Of the two buttons that do work, neither is documented.  I appreciate this form is under development but, if you are going to ask people to help debug it, you should make it easier to do so.

I assume the objective of `update_Click` is to add a new row to the bottom of worksheet "Master".  If this assumption is true then I suggest the following:

```
Public Sub update_Click()

  MsgBox "Directorate has been updated!"

  Dim RowNext As Long

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    ' There is no checking of the values entered by the user.
    ' I have assumed that the surname is present on the last used row.
    ' If this assumption is untrue, the new data will overwrite the row
    ' below the last row with a surname.
    RowNext = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    .Cells(RowNext, "A").Value = surname.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "B").Value = firstname.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "C").Value = tod.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "D").Value = program.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "E").Value = email.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "F").Value = GetCheckBoxes
    .Cells(RowNext, "G").Value = officenumber.Value
    .Cells(RowNext, "H").Value = cellnumber.Value

  End With

End Sub
```

If you confirm that I am on the right track, I have a look at `Search_Click`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tony and my apologies for confusing code - the purpose of the update button is to update whatever i `.find` There's a `r=f.row` in `search` which gives the row of the found item (eg., if i search by surname, Doe) and using the `update` i would replace the name of surname to plumber. So essentially, i search the person by surname and update whatever necessary information i need to update and click `update` to update that `row` ;however this theory doesn't work when i click on the items in the listbox - please let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: I do not know why you do not get a compile error and I do not know what will happen at run time.  `FindNext` is a VBA method.  You are also using findnext as a sub routine name and as a variable within that sub routine.  You should never use keywords as names even if you appear to have got away with it.  Please rename the sub routine and variable.

Comment: Have I got this correct? The user enters a surname and clicks [Search]. `Search_click` search for the first person with that surname.  If the surname is found, it fills in the other controls for the person before checking that only one person has that surname.  The user amends the person's details as required and clicks [Update] to call `Update_Click` to write the details back.

Comment: Yes that's correct - after the person clicks [Search], `Search_click` will find the person with that surname and fill in the textboxes as well as the checkboxes. Then if i want to change the information of that surname, i'll write whatever information and click [Update] which will replace the original to the newly added information. When the `Search_Click` is running, it goes to `findnext` sub which displays all the information onto the listbox. The problem is when i click on 2nd instance from the listbox and try to use the `Update_Click` it only updates the first found instance, not the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is substantial different from yours.  Partly this is because your code did not work while, to the extent I have tested it, mine does.  But most of the changes are because I did not understand your code.  As I worked through your code, I documented it, changed to meaningful names and implemented the effects I thought you were trying to achieve.

When you are creating code, it is important to remember that in six or twelve months you will be back to update it for new requirements.   A little time spent making the code easy to understand as you write it can save hours when you need to maintain it.  Name variables systematically so you immediately know what they are when you return.  Explain what each subroutine and block of code it attempting to achieve so you can find the code you wish to update.

Firstly I have changed your form.  I have made the form a little deeper and moved the listbox down.  Above the listbox I have inserted a label which I have named `lblMessage`.  This label spans the entire width of the form and is three lines deep.  Most of your text is Tahoma 8.  This label is Tahoma 10 and is coloured blue.  I use it to tell the user what they are expected to do.

As the first line of the form's code I have added:

```
Option Explicit
```

Look this statement up to see why it should always be present.

You use Offsets to access the various columns in the worksheet.  This can be a nightmare if the columns are every re-arranged.  I have used constants:

```
Const ColMasterFamilyName As String = "A"
Const ColMasterGivenName As String = "B"
Const ColMasterTitle As String = "C"
Const ColMasterProgArea As String = "D"
Const ColMasterEMail As String = "E"
Const ColMasterStakeHolder As String = "F"
Const ColMasterOfficePhone As String = "G"
Const ColMasterCellPhone As String = "H"
```

This makes my statements much longer than yours but means that instead of 5, say, I have a name.

These constants are named using my system.  "Col" says these are columns.  "Master" says which worksheet they apply to.  "FamilyName" says which column.  In your code you use "surname" and "first name".  I worked for too many years in an area where "surname" and "first name" were not "culturally sensitive".  I am not asking you to like my system but you must have a system.  I can look at code I wrote years ago and know what the variables are.

I have replaced your:

```
Public r As Long
```

with:

```
Dim RowEnteredName() As Long
```

I redimension this array for every select.  If only a single row matches the entered name then it is dimensioned as `ReDim RowEnteredName(1 To 1)` and `RowEnteredName(1)` holds the row number.  If Count rows match the entered name then it is dimensioned as `ReDim RowEnteredName(0 To Count)`.  `RowEnteredName(0)` is not used because it corresponds to the heading line while `RowEnteredName(1 To Count)` hold the row numbers for each repeat of the name.

I have added a form initialisation routine to prepare the form for use.

I have recoded your `findnext` as `FillListBox` because you cannot use keywords as the name for subroutines or variables.

There are routines in your code that I have commented out so that I know the code below is complete.

I hope all this makes sense.

```
Option Explicit

Const ColMasterFamilyName As String = "A"
Const ColMasterGivenName As String = "B"
Const ColMasterTitle As String = "C"
Const ColMasterProgArea As String = "D"
Const ColMasterEMail As String = "E"
Const ColMasterStakeHolder As String = "F"
Const ColMasterOfficePhone As String = "G"
Const ColMasterCellPhone As String = "H"

Dim RowEnteredName() As Long
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
'pop listbox when more than one instances are prompted
'cliking the person's name will change the textboxes
'transfer the values to updateclick

  Dim RowMasterCrnt As Long

  If ListBox1.ListIndex = 0 Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    lblMessage.Caption = "You cannot select the heading row.  Please select a person."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    RowMasterCrnt = RowEnteredName(ListBox1.ListIndex)

    ReDim RowEnteredName(1 To 1)
    RowEnteredName(1) = RowMasterCrnt

    surname.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterFamilyName).Value
    firstname.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterGivenName).Value
    tod.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterTitle).Value
    program.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterProgArea).Value
    email.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterEMail).Value
    Call SetCheckBoxes(.Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterStakeHolder).Value)
    officenumber.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterOfficePhone).Value
    cellnumber.Value = .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterCellPhone).Value
    lblMessage.Caption = "Please change details as required then click [Update].  " & _
                         "If you have selected the wrong person, " & _
                         "please click [Select] to reselect."
    update.Visible = True

  End With

  ListBox1.Visible = False  ' Cannot use again because RowEnteredName changed

End Sub
Private Sub Search_Click()

  ' User should have entered a Family name before clicking Search.
  If surname.Value = "" Then
    Debug.Assert False  ' Not tested
    lblMessage.Caption = "Please enter a Family name or Surname"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Dim Name As String
  Dim CellNameFirst As Range        ' First cell, if any, holding family name
  Dim Count As Long
  Dim FirstAddress As String

  lblMessage.Caption = ""
  Name = surname.Value

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    ' Look for entered family name in appropriate column
    Set CellNameFirst = .Columns(ColMasterFamilyName).Find( _
                            what:=Name, after:=.Range(ColMasterFamilyName & "1"), _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not CellNameFirst Is Nothing Then

      ' There is at least one person with the entered family name.

      ' Fill the listbox and make it visible if there is more than one person
      ' with the entered family name
      'Debug.Assert False  ' Not tested
      Call FillListBox(CellNameFirst)

      If ListBox1.Visible Then
        ' There is more than one person with the entered name
        ' Ensure update not available until selection made from list box
        'Debug.Assert False  ' Not tested
        update.Visible = False
        lblMessage.Caption = "Please click the required person within the listbox"
        Exit Sub
      Else
        ' Only one person with entered name
        ' Prepare the entry controls for updating by the user

        'Debug.Assert False  ' Not tested
        ReDim RowEnteredName(1 To 1)
        RowEnteredName(1) = CellNameFirst.Row   ' Record row for selected family name

        firstname.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterGivenName).Value
        tod.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterTitle).Value
        program.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterProgArea).Value
        email.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterEMail).Value
        Call SetCheckBoxes(.Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterStakeHolder).Value)
        officenumber.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterOfficePhone).Value
        cellnumber.Value = .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), ColMasterCellPhone).Value
        lblMessage.Caption = "Please change details as required then click Update"
        update.Visible = True
      End If
    Else
      Debug.Assert False  ' Not tested
      lblMessage.Caption = "No person found with that name.  Please try another."
      update.Visible = False
    End If

  End With

End Sub
Public Sub update_Click()

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "A").Value = surname.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "B").Value = firstname.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "C").Value = tod.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "D").Value = program.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "E").Value = email.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "F").Value = GetCheckBoxes
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "G").Value = officenumber.Value
    .Cells(RowEnteredName(1), "H").Value = cellnumber.Value

  End With

  ' Clear controls ready for next select and update
  surname.Value = ""
  firstname.Value = ""
  tod.Value = ""
  program.Value = ""
  email.Value = ""
  Call SetCheckBoxes("")
  officenumber.Value = ""
  cellnumber.Value = ""

  lblMessage.Caption = "Please enter the family name or surname of the " & _
                       "person whose details are to be updated then " & _
                       "click [Search]."

  update.Visible = False

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  ' Set controls visible or invisible on initial entry to form.

  ' Update is not available until Search has been clicked and current
  ' details of a single person has been displayed.
  update.Visible = False

  ' The listbox is only used if Search finds the entered name matches
  ' two or more people
  ListBox1.Visible = False

  ' Search is the first button to be clicked and is always available
  ' as a means of cancelling the previous selection.
  Search.Visible = True

  ' Not yet implemented
  CommandButton1.Visible = False
  CommandButton2.Visible = False
  CommandButton3.Visible = False
  CommandButton7.Visible = False

  lblMessage.Caption = "Please enter the family name or surname of the " & _
                       "person whose details are to be updated then " & _
                       "click [Search]."

End Sub
Function ColCodeToNum(ColStg As String) As Integer

  ' Convert 1 or 2 character column identifiers to number.
  ' A -> 1; Z -> 26: AA -> 27; and so on

  Dim lcColStg                  As String

  lcColStg = LCase(ColStg)
  ColCodeToNum = IIf(Len(ColStg) > 1, (Asc(Left(ColStg, 1)) - 64) * 26, 0) + _
                 Asc(Right(ColStg, 1)) - 64

End Function
Sub FillListBox(CellNameFirst As Range)

  ' CellNamefirst is the first, possibly only, cell for the
  ' family name entered by the user.
  ' Clear the listbox.  If there is more than one person with the
  ' entered family name, make the listbox visible and fill it with
  ' every person with the same family name

  Dim CellName As Range
  Dim Count As Long
  Dim ListBoxData() As String
  Dim RowMasterCrnt As Long
  Dim LbEntryCrnt As Long

  Me.ListBox1.Clear
  Set CellName = CellNameFirst

  ' Count number of rows with same family name as CellNameFirst
  Count = 1
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Do While True
      Set CellName = .Columns(ColMasterFamilyName).findnext(CellName)
      If CellName.Row = CellNameFirst.Row Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        Exit Do
      End If
      'Debug.Assert False
      Count = Count + 1
    Loop
  End With

  If Count = 1 Then
    ' Only one person has the entered family name
    'Debug.Assert False
    Me.ListBox1.Visible = False
    Exit Sub
  End If

  'Debug.Assert False
  Set CellName = CellNameFirst

  ReDim ListBoxData(1 To 8, 0 To Count)     ' Row 0 used for column headings
  ReDim RowEnteredName(0 To Count)
  LbEntryCrnt = 0

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

      ' Create column headings
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterFamilyName), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                         .Cells(2, ColMasterFamilyName).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterGivenName), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                          .Cells(2, ColMasterGivenName).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterTitle), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                              .Cells(2, ColMasterTitle).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterProgArea), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                           .Cells(2, ColMasterProgArea).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterEMail), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                              .Cells(2, ColMasterEMail).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterStakeHolder), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                        .Cells(2, ColMasterStakeHolder).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterOfficePhone), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                        .Cells(2, ColMasterOfficePhone).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterCellPhone), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                          .Cells(2, ColMasterCellPhone).Value
      LbEntryCrnt = LbEntryCrnt + 1

    Do While True

      ' For each row with the same family name, add details to array
      RowMasterCrnt = CellName.Row
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterFamilyName), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                             .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterFamilyName).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterGivenName), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                              .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterGivenName).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterTitle), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                  .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterTitle).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterProgArea), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                               .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterProgArea).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterEMail), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                                  .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterEMail).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterStakeHolder), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                            .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterStakeHolder).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterOfficePhone), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                            .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterOfficePhone).Value
      ListBoxData(ColCodeToNum(ColMasterCellPhone), LbEntryCrnt) = _
                              .Cells(RowMasterCrnt, ColMasterCellPhone).Value
      RowEnteredName(LbEntryCrnt) = RowMasterCrnt
      LbEntryCrnt = LbEntryCrnt + 1
      Set CellName = .Columns(ColMasterFamilyName).findnext(CellName)
      If CellName.Row = CellNameFirst.Row Then
        Exit Do
      End If

    Loop
  End With

  Me.ListBox1.Column = ListBoxData  ' Write array to listbox
  ListBox1.Visible = True

End Sub
'Get the checked checkboxes as a space-separated string
Function GetCheckBoxes() As String

  Dim arrStakeHolderAll() As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim rv As String

  'Debug.Assert False
  arrStakeHolderAll = WhatCheckboxes()
  rv = ""

  For i = LBound(arrStakeHolderAll) To UBound(arrStakeHolderAll)
    'Debug.Assert False
    If Me.Controls(arrStakeHolderAll(i)).Value = True Then
      'Debug.Assert False
      rv = rv & IIf(Len(rv) > 0, " ", "") & arrStakeHolderAll(i)
    End If
  Next i

  GetCheckBoxes = rv

End Function
Sub SetCheckBoxes(strList As String)

  ' Populate checkboxes from space-separated values in strList.
  ' Pass "" to just clear checkboxes

  Dim arrStakeHolderAll() As Variant
  Dim arrStakeHolderCrnt() As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim tmp As String

  'Debug.Assert False
  PACT.Value = False
  PrinceRupert.Value = False
  WPM.Value = False
  Montreal.Value = False
  TET.Value = False
  TC.Value = False
  US.Value = False
  Other.Value = False

  arrStakeHolderAll = WhatCheckboxes()

 If Len(strList) > 0 Then
    'Debug.Assert False
    arrStakeHolderCrnt = Split(strList, " ")
    For i = LBound(arrStakeHolderCrnt) To UBound(arrStakeHolderCrnt)
      'Debug.Assert False
      tmp = Trim(arrStakeHolderCrnt(i))
      If Not IsError(Application.Match(tmp, arrStakeHolderAll, 0)) Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        Me.Controls(tmp).Value = True
      End If
    Next i
  End If

End Sub

'returns the name of all Stakeholder checkboxes
Function WhatCheckboxes() As Variant()
  'Debug.Assert False
  WhatCheckboxes = Array("PACT", "PrinceRupert", "WPM", _
                         "Montreal", "TET", "TC", "US", "Other")
End Function
```

Comment: wow i never expected this much detailed answer - thank you. I've copied and pasted your code to see how it would work; but the `lblMessage.Caption` in `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` gives me a `variable not defined` error. You've mentioned that `Commandbutton` are not working - I believe someone else was working on this file he changed the `name` of the `commandbutton`. `addbutton` should be `commandbutton1` `resetbutton` should be `commandbutton3` and `closebutton` should be  `commandbutton2` - my apologies i should have double checked before uploading, i wasn't aware it was changed...

Comment: I explained that I had added a label to the your form.  You will have to do the same to your version.